# How to loop dataframe in R and create two new columns based on lat, long calculation?

Tags: r, csv

I'm really new to R. I'm trying to convert X,Y to Long, Lat in R.

I have a piece of code that I can convert X,Y to Long, Lat. How do I apply that to dataframe and create two new columns (Long, Lat)?

```
data = read.csv('./parking_regulation.csv')

library(proj4)
proj4string <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.66666666666666 +lat_2=41.03333333333333 +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs"

# Source data
xy <- data.frame(x=data['x'], y=data['y'])
xy # But this only convert one row

# Transformed data
pj <- project(xy, proj4string, inverse=TRUE)
latlon <- data.frame(lat=pj$y, lon=pj$x)
# I want to create two new columns from this result lat,long
```

Columns from CSV

```
x                y
1005740.867110  243957.356623
```

Comment: The problem for us is that we cannot see `'./parking_regulation.csv'`. Why not build an example with something similar from an avaialble package or a website?

Comment: I'll edit the question to add the data.

Comment: `xy$lat <- pj$x ; xy$lon=pj$y` ?